# Section names to be only included in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex

I am trying to include PDF files into my Latex document.
I would like the section names to be included in the table of contents, but not as headers in my text.
At the moment it gives me headers in my document, which causes the PDF files I am including to be shifted outside my page.

What changes do I have to make in order to accomplish this?

This is what I have written:

```
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{Section 1}
\includegraphics{Section 1.pdf}

\section{Section 2}

\subsection{Section 2.1}
\includegraphics{Section2_1.pdf}

\subsection{Section 2.2}
\includegraphics{Section2_2.pdf}
```

Comment: If you use `\includepdf` to include entire pages, then it has options to add stuff to the toc.

Comment: Thank you, I have changed to \includepdf which works well. But how can I makes sure the name of the sections are only found in the table of contents and not as a header of the sections in the document itself? Because I only want the PDF I have included to be there without any headings (but at the same time being possible to just click in the table of contents and directly come to this PDF somewhere in my document).

Comment: You should really provide example code so we have a better idea what you are doing (your current code is incomplete). Untested, you might use the `pagecommand` option instead, and then in it run the appropriate `\addcontentesline{toc}{secton}{....}`, note that the `...` part depends on your setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got most of the answer in the comments, but here's an example of what you might do. I've added `\phantomsection` which may help with the hyperlinks in the toc going to the right place.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section 1 Title}
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}]{Section 1.pdf}

\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Subsection 1.1 Title}
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}]{Section1_1.pdf}

\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Subsection 1.2 Title}
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}]{Section1_2.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Remove `pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}` if you don't want page numbers added to the included pdfs.

Or possibly (to include numbers):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\refstepcounter{section}%
\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\thesection. Section 1 Title}
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}]{Section 1.pdf}

\refstepcounter{subsection}%
\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\thesubsection. Subsection 1.1 Title}
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}]{Section1_1.pdf}

\refstepcounter{subsection}%
\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\thesubsection. Subsection 1.2 Title}
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}]{Section1_2.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that is exactly how I wanted it to look like.